# Casting from System.XmlWriter to System.XmlTextWriter

Tags: c#

How can I cast XmlWriter to XmlTextWriter in C#?

thanks

Comment: Can you give us a line or two where you are creating/using your XmlWriter?  As mentioned, it must be *created* as an XmlTextWriter to allow casting - otherwise it's invalid.

Answer (score 1):

XmlTextWriter subclasses XmlWriter, so, if your XmlWriter is indeed an XmlTextWriter, you can just cast it like anything else. If your XmlWriter is any other subclass of XmlWriter, your cast would fail.

You can check the type and then cast

```
if (xmlWriter is XmlTextWriter)
{
    XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = (XmlTextWriter)xmlWriter;
    // add code here
}
```

Or you can use `as` to give it a shot and then see if it worked out.

```
XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = xmlWriter as XmlTextWriter;

if (null != xmlTextWriter)
{
    // add code here
}
```

Comment: It throws an Exception saying "instantiate an object with new keyword"

Answer (score 0):

`XmlTextWriter` is inheriting from `XmlWriter`. So unless the `XmlWriter` you have is an `XmlTextWriter`, you can't cast it that way. You could do

```
var textWriter = xmlWriter as XmlTextWriter;
if (textWriter != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Why not instantiate the `XmlTextWriter` to begin with?

Comment: Because all of existing code is written with XMlWriter. Problem is only its not encoding xml properly. When I use XmlWriter class then it throws an ArgumentException "' ', hexadecimal value 0x05, is an invalid character.". Therefore I am trying to XmlTextWriter because it automatically convert symbols to their corresponding code.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you would perform any other cast (assuming your instance is actually an XmlTextWriter).

The following case below works:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class Test
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
          XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("MyXml.xml");
          XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = xmlWriter as XmlTextWriter;
          if(xmlTextWriter != null)
          {
               //perform operations here...
          }
     }   
}
```

You should note they [recommend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz7cs0d.aspx) using XmlWriter.Create to create XmlWriter instances.

Comment: XmlWriter does not create XmlTextWriter instances - so the null check will never pass.